# Mimic managed component restrictions on scratch orgs

Tags: managed-package, salesforcedx

I'm working on a managed package, whose packaging org is an old, non-DX org. We have migrated all the development to DX scratch orgs. Seeing as they all share the namespace with the packaging org, I was wondering the following;

**Is there any way to mimic the restrictions that we get after components are released in a managed package on scratch orgs that share that namespace?** My use case is that my managed package contains some global classes which I want to modify. Of course, there are quite a lot of limitations on the changes I can make, not all of them are completely obvious. So I would like those limitations to be enforced on my development environments as well, so that I won't notice my mistake only when I'm deploying my changes to my packaging org.